# HANA Could not find table/view

Tags: java, jdbc, hana

I am trying to connect HANA database which is running in Google Cloud Platform. Here is my Java code,

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:sap://myhost:39015/?";
        String user = "MYUSER";
        String password = "PASSWORD";
        System.out.println("Connecting to HANA..!");
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Connection to HANA successful!");
        ResultSet rs = cn.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from \"TWEETS\"");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The `TWEETS` table exists under `SYSTEM` schema, I can able to query `TWEETS` table using HANA Studio (Eclipse plugin). But, when I try to query from java code the following exception occurs.

> com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [259] (at 14): invalid table name:  Could not find table/view TWEETS in schema SYSTEM: line 1 col 15 (at pos 14)
>
> at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.createException(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:334)
>
> at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.generateDatabaseException(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:165)
>
> at com.sap.db.jdbc.packet.ReplyPacket.buildExceptionChain(ReplyPacket.java:104)
>
> at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.execute(ConnectionSapDB.java:1110)
>
> at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.execute(ConnectionSapDB.java:854)
>
> at com.sap.db.jdbc.StatementSapDB.sendCommand(StatementSapDB.java:925)

Note: I tried below combinations as well, but no luck!

```
 1. "select * from TWEETS" 
 2. "select * from SYSTEM.TWEETS"
 3. "select * from \"TWEETS\" 
 4. "select * from \"SYSTEM\".\"TWEETS\""
```

table creation command,

```
    CREATE COLUMN TABLE TWEETS(
    "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "USER_NAME" NVARCHAR(100),
    "CREATED_AT" DATE,
    "TEXT" NVARCHAR (140),
    "HASH_TAGS" NVARCHAR (100),
    PRIMARY KEY("ID")
    );
```

Could you please help me to figure out the problem here?
Thanks!

Comment: From your code the cause is not obvious. I recommend to tracing the JDBC driver to see what commands actually are transferred to HANA.

Comment: Any luck with this? Same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation provided [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.00/en-US/ff15928cf5594d78b841fbbe649f04b4.html), we can observe that there is a problem with the port that you've used in the SAP JDBC connection string.

> The port should be 3 < instance number>15; for example, 30015, if the instance is 00.

By the above explanation, making the necessary changes in the connection string should resolve the issue.

Corrected connection string is now the following (based on the parameters provided in the question):

```
String url = "jdbc:sap://myhost:30015/?databaseName=TWEETS&user=MYUSER&password=PASSWORD";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: My instance number is 90. So, I'm using 39015 port instead of 30015. I tried above connection string, but still same exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"select * from SYSTEM.\"TWEETS\""
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that user "MYUSER" has required access to read the schema and you have confirmed that using HANA SQL Console.
Run the below command both from JDBC and from SQL console and see what is the CURRENT_SCHEMA value returned? It must be same for both JDBC & SQL Console.

```
select current_schema from dummy;
```

If JDBC is returning some other value then first switch to correct schema using

```
set schema schema_having_TWEET_table;
```

Now run the actual query. Share the latest error log if it still fails.
Based on above log-

*table name: Could not find table/view TWEETS in schema SYSTEM: line 1 col 15 (at pos 14)*

it seems you hitting the wrong schema.